# Django linking accounts after signup using social_auth

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I'm using [social_auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) and [userena](http://www.django-userena.org/) for registration on my website. People sign up with **facebook/twitter** or just using userena.

I have been asked to investigate allowing users to link their Facebook account so that the Django app can post on there time line (if allowed to)

**My question is..... can I still use social_auth for this and how?**

My questions stems from not understanding how this can work as all my users are already signed-up. Some signed up using social_auth, facebook others did not. So how can I link them after? Is social_auth even right for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can associate other social accounts with your identity (even after you have already signed up). If you look at [the intro to social-auth](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html) it mentions this specifically:

> Multiple social account associations to a single user

You can see it in action [on the demo page](http://social.matiasaguirre.net/) also. Once you have the Facebook account linked to your user, you can use the [access token](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tokens.html) from social-auth in conjunction with something like [`facepy`](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) to post to the users wall etc.